# Nautilus crashes, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, mkv

Since I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 I've been having this weird problem: every time I right click properties on any .mkv, .mp4, .avi file Nautilus crashes. This had never happened before. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: Happens to me as well. Because it happens quite often, I managed to get what it writes into the terminal: `malloc(): memory corruption (fast)` But it doesn't tell much.

Comment: Could you run nautilus from the command line and retry this action so we can see the crash log?

Answer (score 2):

Purging `gstreamer1.0-vaapi` with

```
sudo apt purge gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: it may not be real solution.
My Nautilus also crashing on ubuntu 18.04 daily. Tried your solution but got :-). `Package 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi' is not installed, so not removed`. That means problem lies somewhere else.